# Business model with APIPlateform

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

We use Symfony 4 + Doctrine + APIPlateform to deliver a HTTP API.

APIPlateform exposes Doctrine entities as API Rest resources (via annotation inside entity class), which (I found) no a good practice, since the business model (exposed by the API) should be the same than the Symfony Doctrine model.

As a result, it more looks like a basic CRUD than a real application.

Am I wrong about that or is it possible to create kind of Doctrine virtual entities in order to use tools like APIPlatform (or even Symfony form)?

Answer (score 0):

It's true that API platform seems to be strongly opinionated towards very simple CRUD cases.

Symfony Form component however will accept any object as the data. We normally use objects like MyThingType (extended from AbstractType) and MyThingDTO (data transfer object) for separating the UI from the business model and persistence layer. Works just fine.

API Platform has kind of a support for DTO's but in my opinion it's not that usable for complex scenarios. For complex application with good separation of concerns and complex business model it would seem that using Symfony controllers/form directly or perhaps with FOS Rest would be more direct way to achieve it.
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/

You can hide some of the internals of your Doctrine entity by serialization groups but it's still not the same as real separation.